# Symfony 4 - How tu use service.yaml parameter from within Entity

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm trying to use a parameter that i've set in service.yaml as such :

parameters:
    **app.path.users_profile_picture:** uploads/users/profile-picture

Directly from within a User Entity, And I can't figure out how to do this ?

Comment: In my point of view, this is a wrong approach. You cant inject services or service parameteres into an entity.

You should go ahead with a service, which is injected into the controller, where you then grab the base path for the userprofile pictures.

Comment: The thing is that for VichUploaderbundle I had to set up this parameter in service.yaml and I need to use this value in my User Entity, it would be cleaner if I use this parameter instead of rewriting the path in my entity

Comment: I have VichUploadebundle too, but i dont need to have the service parameter in my entity.

Comment: I do this for my own reason. But anyway, so there is no way to achieve what I want .. ?

Comment: No, in my point of view its not possible and its not necessary. But still some confusion about your question in fact of, that you have no path in your db when you use VichUploader. VichUploader has its definition on the yaml file and whenever you call the VichUploader field, this parameters would be accessed automatically.

Comment: I have no isue using vichUploader, I'm just trying to do this                             
   public function getProfilePicture(): ?string
    {
        return '/uploads/users/profile-picture/'.$this->profilePicture;
    } it is more convenient for my needs to return the whole path instead of adding the prefix before rendering the image. Also I will need to use it as an api

Comment: I think you have not used the vich_uploader_asset to display the image nah? {{ vich_uploader_asset(Entity.Field, 'NameOfDefinitionInYAMLForUpload') }}. Replace Entity.Field with your entity.profilePicture

Comment: Please don’t tell me you want to mess with the file system inside entities. This smells like miles away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do or why, it does look like there may be a better way of achieving what you want.

That being said, it is possible to use a parameter from your `services.yaml` in an entity, but you can't inject it directly in the entity's constructor. If you're using Doctrine you can inject it by subscribing to the `postLoad` event, which is dispatched after an entity is constructed by the `entityManager`.

Let's say you have a `User` entity with an attribute for the services.yaml param you want tu use:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

private $serviceArgument;

class User
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getServiceArgument()
    {
        return $this->serviceArgument;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $serviceArgument
     */
    public function setServiceArgument($serviceArgument): void
    {
        $this->serviceArgument = $serviceArgument;
    }
}
```

You need an `EventSubscriber` so you can do stuff on the `postLoad` event:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class UserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $serviceArgument;

    // Inject param from services.yaml
    public function __construct($serviceArgument)
    {
        $this->serviceArgument = $serviceArgument;
    }

    // Listen to postLoad event
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::postLoad,
        );
    }

    // Set the services.yaml param on the entity
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $user = $args->getObject();

        if ($user instanceof User) {
            $user->setServiceArgument($this->serviceArgument);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `services.yaml` you need to configure the subscriber and pass the param you want:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true     
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false       

    App\EventSubscriber\UserSubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
        arguments:
            $serviceArgument: 'Argument from my services.yaml'
```

Now you can use your param in your entity (`User::getServiceArgument()`).